# How to get array index number by specific value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

Its a json data.

```
"score":[
    {
        "userId":"5",
        "playtime":"1396369254",
        "score":"25"
    },
    {
        "userId":"3",
        "playtime":"1396369246",
        "score":"2"
    },
    {
        "userId":"1",
        "playtime":"1396369056",
        "score":"12"
    },
    {
        "userId":"2",
        "playtime":"1396369240",
        "score":"100"
    }
],
```

I want to print array index number which userId value is 1.

Comment: You would have to loop over and check each one until you find the one you want. Other than that you could loop over the entire thing once and index them under the `userId` making access faster/easier.

Comment: There are functions like `array_search` and `in_array` but they don't apply here because you are handling complex structures. You will have to write your own search algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Use a foreach as such:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
    if($value['userId'] == 1) {
        print $key;
        break;
    }
}
```